# How can I print values to the left of my table?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, html-table, output

I need to print the values to the left of the table like shown here:

[image]

I know how to input the variables and text, just not sure where to insert code and  how to position correctly.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function fixVal(value,numberOfCharacters,numberOfDecimals,padCharacter) { 
    var i, stringObject, stringLength, numberToPad;            

    value = value * Math.pow(10,numberOfDecimals);                 
    value = Math.round(value);                                   
    stringObject = new String(value);                            
    stringLength = stringObject.length;                          
    while(stringLength < numberOfDecimals + 1) {                     
        stringObject = "0"+stringObject;                    
        stringLength = stringLength+1;                      
    }

    if(numberOfDecimals > 0) {                     
        stringObject = stringObject.substring(0,stringLength-numberOfDecimals)+"."+
        stringObject.substring(stringLength-numberOfDecimals,stringLength);
    }

    if (stringObject.length < numberOfCharacters && numberOfCharacters>0) {
        numberToPad=numberOfCharacters-stringObject.length;      
        for (i=0; i<numberToPad; i=i+1) {
            stringObject=padCharacter+stringObject;
        }
    }

    return stringObject;                                      
}

function buildTable() {

    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("loanAmt").value );
    var monthly = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPay").value );
    var rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("intRte").value );

    rate = rate / 100 / 12;

    var msg = "<table id='tablefont' border='3' width='65%'>";
    msg += "<tr>";
    msg += "<td>Month</td>";
    msg += "<td>Principal Paid</td>";
    msg += "<td>Interest Paid</td>";
    msg += "<td>Loan Balance</td>";
    msg += "</tr>";

    newPrincipal=amount;
    var m = 1;   //months

    while ( amount > 0 ) {
        var interest = amount * rate;
        var principal = monthly - interest;

        if (principal > amount) {
            principal = amount;
            amount = 0.0;
        } else {
            amount -= principal;
        }

        msg += "<tr><td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>"+m+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>$"+fixVal(principal,0,2,' ')+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>$"+fixVal(interest,0,2,' ')+"</td> \
                <td align='left' bgcolor='pink'>$"+fixVal(amount,0,2,' ')+"</td></tr>";

        m++;
    }


    msg += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = msg;


}


</script>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    background: black;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contentwrap {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
    background: #FFFFCC;
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px red solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 40px;
}

#tablewrap {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 10px pink solid;
}

#tablefont {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

table {
    border: 5px blue solid;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-shadow: yellow 3px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    color: red;
}

#button {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}

.contentTitles {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.style {
    background: lightblue;
    font-family: comic sans ms;
    border: 6px blue double;
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="contentwrap">

<div id="header">Javascript Loan Calculator</div>

<form>

<div class="contentTitles">Enter Loan Amount<br />
<input type="text" id="loanAmt" class="style"><p />

Interest Rate (%)<br />
<input type="text" id="intRte" class="style"><p /> 

Monthly Payment Amount<br />
<input type="text" id="monthlyPay" class="style"><p />

<div style="margin-top:20px;">
<input type="button" value="Process Data" id="button" onClick="buildTable()">
</div>

</form>

<center>
<div id="results" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
</center>


</div> <!-- ends div#contentwrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try making two divs.  One for the values on the left and one for the table. then `float:left;`

Comment: Do i need to declare another variable since msg is used for the table?Just tried this: msg += "<div>Loan Amount: " + amount +"</div>";  But it won't work right

Comment: What i was thinking was just putting another div to the left of your `results` div, which would contain the details you want beside the table. Basically make another div and make another message to display inside it like `document.getElementById("results_details").innerHTML = results_msg;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.
EDIT: I think it's better to prepare the overview at the same time as the results (so rename `buildTable` to `buildResults`:

```
function buildResults() {
```

(same as current build table) PLUS:

```
    var msg2 = "";
    msg2 += "Loan Amount: " + document.getElementById("loanAmt").value + "<br>";
    msg2 += "Annual Interest: " + document.getElementById("intRte").value + "<br>";
    msg2 += "Monthly Payment: " + document.getElementById("monthlyPay").value + "<br>";

    document.getElementById("overview").innerHTML = msg2;
```

Change the button definition:

```
<input type="button" value="Process Data" id="button" onClick="buildResults();">
```

Add a div and float it to the left of the div with the centered table:

```
<div id="overview" style="margin-top:20px;margin-right:20px;float:left;align:left;"></div>
```

Of course, there is some more formatting and cleanup to do to have it exactly match what you are looking for.

Comment: This method works. But now Im running into formula problems when needing to display the proper value. `var msg2 = "";
    msg2 += "Loan Amount: $" + document.getElementById("loanAmt").value + "<br>";
    msg2 += "Annual Interest: " + document.getElementById("intRte").value + "%" +"<br>";
    msg2 += "Monthly Payment: $" + document.getElementById("monthlyPay").value + "<br>";
 msg2 += "Monthly Interest:  " + fixVal(interest,0,2,' ') +"<br>";
 msg2 += "Months to pay off loan: " +m+"<br>";
 msg2 += "Total Interest Paid: $" + "<br>"; `

Comment: Oh really, damn. How urgent is this? Can I get back to you tomorrow with the formulas that you need to get the values to be displayed to the left of the table.

Comment: It's due in a few hours unfortunately. Can't seem to figure out the formulas for the total interest paid and the monthly interest. After that I'm done with the assignment. Everything comes up fine to the left, just the ones i mentioned have incorrect values.

Comment: Well, sum up each monthly interest amount (within the while loop which displays the monthly amounts in the table). The monthly interest amount starts large and decreases down to zero in the last month. You already calculate the monthly interest: var interest = amount * rate; There is a complex formula to calculate the total monthly interest, but make it easy on your self and just add each monthly amount of interest into some var.

Comment: Ah, I see. You put fixVal( interest, 0, 2, ' ') but at the end of the while loop, the interest = 0.